# Build Uber like data model for OLAP

Tags: data-modeling, olap, datamodel

I am building up data model and I was trying a data model for Rideshare

Here is what I have so far

Trip Fare Fact table
Timestamp
TripId
DriverId
RiderId
TripStatus(Cancelled_by_driver, Cancelled_by_rider, matched, completed)
SrcLocation
DstLocation
TripCost

Dimension tables:
Driver
DriverId
Name.
Address.
PaymentId
CarMakeAndModel
Rating

Rider
RiderId.
Name.
Address.
PaymentId.

I can create dimension table for Timestamp, address, PaymentId. What other things I should try.

Let us say if I want to calculate number of trips taken by Driver/Rider per day over last x days. How does the data get rolled up for this.